# Modifying boolean value in Action Listeners

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, swt

### Code:

```
    final boolean saveedit = true;

    btnSaveEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (saveedit) {

                // save function
                if (txtMessage.getText().length() != 0) {
                    message = txtMessage.getText();

                }
                // show popup

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmEventsAndProperties,
                        "Your last message is: " + message, "Message",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                btnSaveEdit.setText("Edit");
                txtMessage.setEnabled(false);
                saveedit = false;
            } else {
                // edit function

            }
        }
    });
```

### Error:

> 'The final local variable `saveedit` cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type'.

### Question:

I have seen other solutions for similar same errors, yet there must be a simple way to implement it - probably as simple as defining something earlier or moving it around.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Wherenver you want to use a variable inside an inner class (here `ActionListener`), you have two choices (regarding how you want to use it, modify(mutate) or access):

1. Using the `final` keyword with a local variable (it is **not recommended** for your case, since you want to *modify* your variable inside the inner class, *not access only*)
2. Using a field vairable, that need not be `final` (it is **recommended**)

As I mentioned, the seconed solution is feasible for you, since you want to do `saveedit = false;` which is mutating.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with *sager89*. But i want to add one thing here which is.

**If the keyword final is used for an instance variable, Then the final variable can be assigned only once and at the time of declaration or you will have to assign it in each and every constructor once.**

Answer (score 0):

This question is not a duplicate, the answer is for anyone wondering to simply move

`final boolean saveedit = true;`
to inbetween these lines:

```
btnSaveEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

That way it is not defined in an enclosing type :)